# 301 redirect to all pages in a site with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to set up a 301 redirect from a .co.uk site to a .com site, keeping the same pages.

So someone going to mydomain.co.uk/pages/about should get redirected to mydomain.com/pages/about

I'm using ASP.NET and IIS 7.0 and not having much luck.  I tried setting a custom 404 file that has a redirect in it like so:

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains(".co.uk"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace(
                ".co.uk",
                ".com"));
    }
```

however my 404 page isn't being called when I go to a URL such as /pages/about.  I have the following in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="404.aspx"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Application_BeginRequest function of the global.asax.  Much cleaner than trying to redirect to a 404

Answer (score 0):

`customErros section` within your *web.config* will be accessed in case there is an error in your application. Is there any error when try to navigate to  mydomain.co.uk/pages/about?

If there is no error - customErrors is not affected. In this case you may try `Response.Redirect("mydomain.com/pages/about")`.

See [HttpResponse.Redirect on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (cite: *ASP.NET performs the redirection by returning a 302 HTTP status code.*)

And have a look at [customErrors section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [errors element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2f4e3e7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

please see also http://www.idea-r.it/Blog.aspx/asp-net-301-redirect?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=rss

it addresses the issue very nicely!